# How to generate URL address of post

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I will try to explain and give you people all information you need to help me to solve this problem which i have.

Structure of my website is like this:

1. `site.com/en/index.php`
2. `site.com/en/products/index.php`
3. `site.com/en/products/category/index.php`
4. `site.com/en/products/category/product.php?id=123`

**What kind of problem i have?**

When i retrive product's from database on page `site.com/en/products/category/index.php` and add URL address of products, that look's like this `<a href="site.com/en/products/category/product.php?id=<?php echo $post['post_id']; ?>">Product title</a>` and member of site when click on that URL they go to see all information about that product. That code work. Every product have category which it belongs so some product will be on `site.com/en/products/apple-phones/` other product will be `...products/lg-phone/`

**What i need?**

When user go to `site.com/en/index.php` and look section new products and retrive from database, how i can generate to recognize which category product belongs and generate url by product category and when user click on some product which one will be displayed on new products section go to example `site.com/en/products/apple-phone/product.php?id=4124`. I hope you understand me, i need to generate how to recognize which category product belong and put into url.

**Code on index.php page**

```php
include_once('connection.php');
$post = new Product;
$check = new Product;
$posts = $post->new_products();
class Product {
    public function new_products() {
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `product` ORDER BY `post_date` LIMIT 0,4');
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    }
    public function fetch_data($pid){
        global $pdo;
        $query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `product` ORDER BY `post_date` LIMIT 0, 4');
        $query->BindValue(1,$pid);
        $query->execute();
        return $query->fetch();
    }
}
```

and now code for displaying product's:

```php
<?php foreach($posts as $post){?>
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="small">
        <p class="img-wrap">
            <a href="?????"><img src="site.com/en/<?php echo $post['post_image']?>" width="405" height="304" alt="" /></a>
        </p>
        <h5><?php echo $post['post_title'];?></h5>
        <p class="h4"><?php echo substr($post['post_content'], 0, 60) . '... <a href="????">Read more...</a>'; ?></p>
<?php }?>
```

I hope this information will be help to give me best solution how to do this.

Thanks all,

PS. sorry for my english

Comment: You bind value but I don't see any parameters in your query.

Comment: In this script are not writed code for resolving my problem, because i don't know what to write or how to solve this problem... @Dharman

Comment: @Marck we can't see your table structures, so it's impossible to say conclusively how you would accomplish your objective... but the query in `new_products()` needs to be returning that information so that `$post['something_goes_here']` contains that product type slug and can be used to build the URL.  The value for `'something_goes_here'` should be a column in your table, or from another table that you need to join in that query to get the answer. Your question seems to be about finding that value, and we can't tell you how to do that based on the information provided.

Comment: I will give you information just tell me what tipe of information? @Michael-sqlbot